# Ubuntu 22.04 Installation error from Microsoft Store

Tags: 22.04, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 on my Windows from the Microsoft store. it was working fine. Then I uninstalled it a few days after installation. Even after uninstallation, I can see the folder in the left pane of Windows Explorer. There I can see the Ubuntu folder is still there. Since then I have been trying to install it again and getting an error.

> It looks like you're not online. When you reconnect, downloading will pick up where it left off.
> and the error code is `Code: 0x800704C6`

Can someone please help me install it again?

When I clicked installed for the first time after uninstalling. it downloaded it nearly 500+ MB and showed me a message installing but failed. Whenever I clicked install after that I can see downloading for 1 second and then it turns into installing and then I get the error I gave above.

Comment: Does `wsl -l -v` show a distribution?  If so, that leftover might be what's interfering with the new install attempt.  Assuming you don't need anything from that old distribution try `wsl --unregister <distroname>` to get rid of it.  Keep in mind that this is a **destructive**, irreversible action with no confirmation that will remove the Ubuntu distribution (and *all* files that are in it).  After that, reboot and see if (at least) the Linux share is gone from File Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your help. it worked. `wsl --unregister` solved my problem

Comment: Great to hear you got it resolved. In that case, I've moved my comment to an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `wsl -l -v` shows a distribution then that leftover might be what's interfering with the new install attempt.

Assuming you don't need anything from that old distribution try `wsl --unregister <distroname>` to get rid of it. Keep in mind that this is a **destructive**, irreversible action with no confirmation that will remove the Ubuntu distribution (and all files that are in it).

After that, reboot and see if (at least) the Linux share is gone from File Explorer.

---

<sub>*Moved from comments to an answer since the OP confirmed that this worked.*</sub>